Doubt in Mobius geometry
I am currently studying Mobius geometry. I found a group in Mobius geometry called Mobius group which contains Mobius transformations. I have the following doubt.
Dose this group contain transformations of the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ only? or the group contains $f(z)=\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$ type functions also.
Kindly help. It will be great if anyone suggests some references to understand it.
Reference: W. Benz, Classical Geometries in Modern Context, Birkhauser Basel, 2012.

Note $\bar{z}$ is not holomorphic so $1/\bar{z}$ is not meromorphic.

Special case $a=d=0$ leads to the inverse function, also seen in stereographic projection as part.
